# How is Google PageSpeed Round Trip represented in Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-pagespeed

In Google PageSpeed Insights under mobile render-blocking JavaScript and CSS section, the comments may refer to the number of server Round Trips before content is displayed.

What does a server Round Trip look like in Google Chrome Developer Network Tools? When I look at the network overview, it looks like the TCP requests are grouped into blocks of 10. Is a Round Trip one of these blocks of 10? If so, is the Round Trip measure only applicable to the start of a website load as the blocks of 10 start to merge as the various elements take different times to load.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing?hl=en),

> Time spent waiting for the initial response, also known as the Time To First Byte. This time captures the latency of a round trip to the server in addition to the time spent waiting for the server to deliver the response.

This is displayed as a green bar (TTFB) in the resourcing timing views.

Comment: Am not sure you are right, I think they are different things.

Comment: The TTFB is the time for a round trip of a request to the server. (Not including DNS lookup and SSL connection.) Your "blocks of 10" maybe referring to the TCP connection limit to a single host for HTTP 1.1 which is 6 connections. So you might be seeing those 6 saturated plus a few requests to other resources. Overall, without seeing what you are seeing it is hard to tell anymore than this to explain your situation. Please provide a screenshot or the URL you're working with for verification of what you are seeing.